# The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint. Even though the correct mapping is used

Tags: java, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code in a .net application:

```
public GradeMapper()
        {
            ToTable("Grades");

            // Primary key
            HasKey(c => c.GradeId);

            // Properties

            //Relations
            HasOptional(g => g.DeterminateTableProp).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("DeterminateTableId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
```

In my database I have this:

[image: Database contents]

I'm using a JavaFX application to make adjustments to the database.
I want to delete a determinatetable, but not the grade where it belongs to.

This is the code I use to delete it:

```
public void deleteDeterminateTableById(int id){
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(findDeterminateTableById(id));
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

But now I get this error:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20141202-3914740): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Grades_dbo.DeterminateTable_DeterminateTableId". The conflict occurred in database "HOGENT1415_11", table "dbo.Grades", column 'DeterminateTableId'.
Error Code: 547
Call: DELETE FROM DeterminateTable WHERE (DETERMINATETABLEID = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: DeleteObjectQuery(domain.DeterminateTable@ee66dbe)
```

So what is wrong with my mapping? I want the foreign key in the Grade table to be set to null when the determinate table is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

you have foreign key on the table you can set it to CASCADE DELETE, and update, this will solve your issue when you delete the parent which have child.

Comment: Does that delete the grade also or not?

Comment: But i want to keep the grade object, not delete it

Comment: then do update and set the foeign key to be null instead of delete

Comment: I cant find how to do this in fluent api

Comment: public void deleteDeterminateTableById(int id){
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        YourObject xyz = findDeterminateTableById(id) ;
         xyz.set...(null);
         
        em.merge(xyz);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: not sure if it is merge, save, or update. but one of  them most work for you

Comment: I mean use your find by id method which is findDeterminateTableById(id) to get the object you need, then set what ever you want in it to be null, then instead of remove, use update, merge, or save(I am not sure what API you use for mapping but it must have update method) and this will make you foreign key null instead of deleting it